# How to avoid Delaunay.find_simplex function from returning -1

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay, simplex, scipy-spatial

I have a set of 500 7D array of points.
When I run the below code:

```py
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
delau = Delaunay(ip)
Delaunay.find_simplex(delau,ip)
```

`Delaunay.find_simplex` returns -1 for only one data point out of 500. I understand that this point lies outside the triangulation and hence gets the value -1.
How can I include this point within triangulation without altering the dimension of the array?